# Determine logic in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have `values` array with booleans:

```
values = [true, false, true];
```

How to determine logic using regex declared in `logic`:

```
logic = "0 AND (1 OR 2)";
```

Result shoud be `true`.

To be more complex it shoud know other operators like `||` (or), `&&` (and), `!` (not).

And handle more complicated logic ... for example `!(0 OR 1) && ( (5 && 3) OR !4) OR 2`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using regular expressions for something like this.

Comment: @arshajii and what shoud I do? :/

Comment: For a start you can tell us what language/tool you're using...

Comment: @arshajii javascript (but I dont think Its important info but ok)

Comment: It most certainly *is* important info -- an answer would completely depend on it. In the future, please include this information in your question (I've added a tag for you in this case).

Comment: @Shaddow I think you have no idea of the *true* complexity of this problem. You want to do this with regex ? And more over with Javascript which doesn't even support lookbehinds, let alone recursive patterns and some other handful stuff.

Comment: OK so if it's javascript we can combine it with `eval` function ... so what about replace numbers with values and then `eval` string.

I would avoid `eval` function but it's best idea I have.

Comment: For preparing the string to evaluate: it seems that you can use a function when replacing regex matches like `logic.replace(/(\d+)/g, fnc);` using `function fnc(idx) { return values[idx]; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand any logic expression into [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), which can be converted to a regular expression fairly easily:

- Sort the literals in each conjunction and replace them with `true` if they are positive, `false` if they are negative, or `(true|false)` if the literal doesn't appear.
- Concatenate the literals in each conjunction.
- Concatenate the conjunctions, separated by `|`.

So for example, `0 AND (1 OR 2)` becomes `(0 AND 1) OR (0 AND 2)` which would become `(true true (true|false))|(true (true|false) true)`, which matches `true false true`.

Note that it would be much easier to just evaluate the expression:

```
function match(values, expression) {
    return eval(expression.replace(/[0-9]+/g, "values[$&]"));
}
```

Example:

```
match([true, false, true], "0 && (1 || 2)"); // => true
```

Comment: yeah its working - http://jsfiddle.net/L2zxs/ ... I'll wait 1 day and then accept if there will not be better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an expression tree, I think.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree

You need to parse a string which represents the expression, then 
build such a tree and then when you have values for the placeholders 
like 0,1,2,3, etc. you use the tree and calculate the value by visiting
each node of the tree in the proper order.

You should research a bit more on this.
This is classic programming stuff.

I hope I understood your question correctly.